# Redux action not getting called the second time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have two redux actions which call as follows.

```
export function action1(params) {
  //This line is always called.
  return (dispatch) => {
    //This line is not called the second time.
    return MyApi.call1(params)
    .then(response => {
      // some logic
      return dispatch(someFunction1());
    })
    .catch(error => {
      throw(error);
    });
  };
}

export function action2(params) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return MyApi.call2(params)
    .then(response => {
      // call the first API again
      action1();
      return dispatch(someFunction2());
    })
    .catch(error => {
      throw(error);
    });
  };
}
```

When the view is first loaded, `action1` is called within the constructor of the view. Upon performing an action and triggering `action2` in the same view, `action1` needs to be called on `action2`'s success to get the updated list from the server. Unfortunately, code breaks without any error when `action1` is called the second time.

What am I missing here?

Comment: btw, you have not dispatched the action1 , like : `dispatch(action1(params)) `;

Comment: It worked. It was so silly of me. Can you post this as an answer so that I can  accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not dispatched the `action1`.

`dispatch( action1( params ) )`

Invoking `action1()` without `dispatch` just returns a function. In order to get `dispatch` in returned function, you should `dispatch` that function. Then it will be caught by `redux-thunk` middleware. The middleware will pass `dispatch` and invoke function.